# Export Access table to Excel, but have different sheets for each name

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to export a table to Excel, but have separate sheets for each name.

Below is code I found but there is a couple of issues.

- I want to pull from a table and the code is set up to pull a query (I think I can just change qdef to TableDef).
- When I try to compile it I get a Invalid outside procedure message.

```vb
Dim Db As DAO.Database, qdef AS DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [CustomerName] FROM [QueryName]")

Do While Not rst.EOF
Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("[MyTempQuery"])
qdef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [QueryName] WHERE Customer = '" & rst!CustomerName & "'"

Set qdef = Nothing
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "MyTempQuery", _
              "C:\Path\To\Excel\Files\" & rst!CustomerName & ".xlsx", True
rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```

Here are the changes I made:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database, tdef As DAO.TableDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [DM_NAME] FROM [RD Completed Report TBL]")

Do While Not rst.EOF
Set tdef = db.TableDefs("[My TempQuery]")
tdef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [RD Completed Report TBL] WHERE DM = '" & rst!DM & "'"

Set qdef = Nothing
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "MyTempQuery", _
              "C:\Path\To\Excel\Files\" & rst!DMS & ".xlsx", True
rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: TableDefs do not have an .SQL property. Why do you need to replace QueryDef for TableDef? Please explain the problem with first block of code.

Comment: Hi Parfait, the problem I'm getting with the first block of code is a Compile Error: invalid outside procedure with the first Set db

Comment: You have the closing bracket outside the quoted query name.

Comment: Yes I fixed that, and am still receiving the same message

Comment: `Set` calls cannot be placed outside a `Sub` or `Function`. In fact it unclear if your code is encapsulated in a subroutine or function.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a QueryDef object, a TableDef does not have an `.SQL` property. See MSDN docs and compare the properties of [QueryDef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-members-dao) and [TableDef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/tabledef-members-dao). In relational databases, a *table* is a physical entity of stored data whereas a *query* (or *view*) essentially is a saved SQL script (one or more statements) used to retrieve data when query is later run. MS Access queries can only save a single SQL statement and stores no data.

Given your SQL statement differs between both code blocks, you appear to believe `TableDefs` can only query tables and `QueryDefs` can only query queries. First, a `TableDef` cannot query at all. Secondly, a `QueryDef` in MS Access can query a table and/or query. That is, any SQL statement can source from *any* table and *any* saved query in the database, even join between the two types of objects. Below examples should work in `QueryDef`. Therefore, continue using `QueryDefs` if needing to filter by SQL for exporting data to Excel worksheets.

Single Table

```sql
SELECT ... FROM [myTable] WHERE ...
```

Single Query

```sql
SELECT ... FROM [mySavedQuery] WHERE ...
```

Two tables

```sql
SELECT ... 
FROM [myTable] t1
INNER JOIN [myTable] t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE ...
```

Table and query

```sql
SELECT ... 
FROM [myTable] t
INNER JOIN [mySavedQuery] q ON t.ID = q.ID
WHERE ...
```

Two queries

```sql
SELECT ... 
FROM [mySavedQuery] q1
INNER JOIN [mySavedQuery] q2 ON q1.ID = q2.ID
WHERE ...
```